# Why does "return *this" return a reference?

Tags: c++

In my C++ class they were discussing how to create an assignment operator.  At the end of the assignment was the line "return *this," which they said returned a reference to the object that "this" points to.  Why does it return a reference?  If "this" is being dereferenced, shouldn't it just return the object?

Comment: im not sure ...but most probably your return type is something like "int&" instead of simple "int", did you notice that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function returns a reference if its declaration (i.e. its signature) tells so.

So (assuming a `class Foo`) if a function is declarated

```
 Foo fun();
```

then it returns a value (with copying, etc..)

But if it is declared as

```
 Foo& fun();
```

or as

```
 const Foo& fun();
```

a reference is returned.

The statement `return *this;` don't define by itself if a reference or a value is returned.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thanks!  I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 4):

It returns the current instance of the type MyClass you are in. It's returned as reference because the assignment operator was explicitly told to return a reference.

```
MyClass& operator = (MyClass& other)  { return *this; }
```

Note the `&` after MyClass as the return value. A reference is returned.
Unless the `&` weren't there right before `operator`, the instance would be returned by value.

Comment: This seems like a circular answer. No code was shown in the question; we were merely told about a function that returns a reference. What was asked is "_why_?" Demonstrating a random function that has a reference return type doesn't seem to cover that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the issue was described quiet good using an example and I'm pretty sure his book is using a similar function. Correct me if it isn't a distinct answer :).

Comment: I have a different interpretation of the question to you. You seem to have read it as "what, in the code, makes my function return a reference?" The question's last sentence makes that seem unlikely to me.

Answer (score 3):

#### The expression `*this`

> At the end of the assignment was the line "return *this," which they said returned a reference to the object that "this" points to

They were wrong.

> Why does it return a reference?

It doesn't.

> If "this" is being dereferenced, shouldn't it just return the object?

Yes!

Dereferencing a pointer yields an *lvalue*. That means that the result of `*this` is the actual object that `this` points to. It's not a reference, but it's not a copy either.

> `[C++11: 5.3.1/1]:` **The unary `*` operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points.** If the type of the expression is “pointer to `T`,” the type of the result is “`T`.” [..]

It can be hard to conceptualise, since you can never do this yourself in code; it's just a feature of the `*` operator for native pointers, and has been since C.

---

#### Returning from `operator=`

Because you can't do it yourself, conventionally you'd bind that *lvalue* expression to a reference in order to use it in different contexts. For example, the expression `*this` in `return *this` gets bound to the return type of the function that you're returning from; in this case, an assignment operator.

Now, we could have the assignment operator return by value in which case an object copy would be made from the lvalue that comes from `*this`; however, for an assignment operator we usually return by reference so that we avoid an almost-certainly needless copy, and can perform *chaining*:

```
Type a, b, c;
c = b = a;
```

It's a convention with benefits, and no downsides. Can you think of a situation when you'd want `op=` to return by value?

Answer (score 1):

Every dereferenced pointer is a reference to its pointee, else you'd 'loose' the pointee you're pointing to.

Invoke method twice on the same object, using a pointer and a reference:

```
MyClass* objPtr = .... ;
objPtr->doSomething();
MyClass& objRef = *objPtr;
objRef.doSomething();
```

Invoke method on distinct objects; original and copy:

```
MyClass* objPtr = .... ;
objPtr->doSomething();
MyClass objCopy = *objPtr; //here, the reference is passed to the (implicit or implemented) copy constructor if possible, else a compile time error occurs.
objCopy.doSomething();
```

That means, if you return a reference from an operator method which has MyClass (rvalue) instead of MyClass& (lvalue) as return type, a copy of *this (MyClass&) is created by reference (leaving aside return value optimizations and rvalue references).
This is useful for non modifying const methods such as + and - which have a new value as result while leaving the object on which this method was invoked unmodified.

Operators like += and your assignment operator modify the object inplace by convention and should therefore return a reference to allow expressions like primitive types support it, since a temporary copy may vanish and cause unexpected results:

Consider this expression:

```
int i = 4;
int r = (i += 3) <<= 2;
```

The result r is 28 (added and shifted inplace).
What is the value of i? 28 too, what else.

But what if hypothetically int::operator+= would return a copy of itself instead of a reference to itself?

The result r would be 28 too.

But the value of i?
It would be 7, since the inplace left shift was applied to a temporary int returned from the addition which gets assigned to r after that.

Continuing the assumption, the error may have the same effect (except for the value in i) as this expression:

```
int r = (i + 3) <<= 2;
```

But luckily, the compiler will complain, that he doesn't have an lvalue reference from (i + 3) to do the shift/assignment operation.

But play with this:

```
class Int
{
private:
    int val;
public:
    Int(int val) :
            val(val)
    {
    }

    Int operator+(const Int& other)const
    {
        return val + other.val;
    }
    Int operator+(int prim)const
    {
        return val + prim;
    }

    Int& operator+=(const Int& other)
    {
        val += other.val;
        return *this;
    }
    //Error here, Int& would be correct
    Int operator+=(int prim)
    {
        val += prim;
        return *this;
    }

    Int operator<<(const Int& other)const
    {
        return val << other.val;
    }
    Int operator<<(int prim)const
    {
        return val << prim;
    }

    Int& operator<<=(const Int& other)
    {
        val <<= other.val;
        return *this;
    }
    Int& operator<<=(int prim)
    {
        val <<= prim;
        return *this;
    }

    operator int()const{
        return val;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Int i = 4;
    Int r = (i += 3) <<= 2;

    cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the * always means a value, in fact you can look to en English interpretation for these operators as follows:

`&`: the address of

`*`: the value of

So when you say `&x` it means "the address of x" and when you say `*x` it means "the value that x points to". So `*this` will always return a value.

Just be sure that the function itself that the hosts the returning is not a reference function. Please remember that in C++ you can create functions with the & or the * operators as well.