# Returning this pointer when the return type of a function is a reference (C++)

Tags: c++, class, reference, this-pointer

There is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048379/why-does-return-this-return-a-reference) but I do not understand the following:

Imagine that I have a class for 2D mathematical vectors and I want to define the setter functions:

```
/** Setters **/
Vector2D& setX(double xcoor) {x = xcoor; return *this;}
Vector2D& setY(double ycoor) {y = ycoor; return *this;}
```

Now, the "this" pointer contains the address of the instance for which the functions are called.

```
Vector2D VV(2,4);
VV.setX(1).setY(5);
```

In this case "this" has the address of the VV instance. So why not just return this but return *this?

Comment: Because the function returns a reference, `this` is a pointer, and `*this` is a reference.   A pointer is not a reference.

Comment: But *this means to dereference the pointer so you get the object that the pointer points to. Right?

Comment: Yes, and then you return a reference to that object.

Comment: Yes `*this` dereferences a pointer. But dereference is a computer science term for allowing manipulation of an object given only its address in memory.  A pointer is not the object it points at - it is a variable that contains the address in memory of an object. Dereferencing a pointer refers to using the pointer to manipulate (or access) the object that pointer points at. It doesn't mean "get the object that the pointer points to" although it can sometimes seem that way.  So dereferencing a pointer can produce a reference.  But a reference and a pointer are distinct concepts.

Comment: @Peter Ok, this answer helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> In this case "this" has the address of the VV instance.

Right.

> So why not just return this but return *this?

Suppose `setX` would return the pointer

```
Vector2D* setX(double xcoor) {x = xcoor; return this;}
      //^--- no reference but pointer        ---^
```

then your code would be wrong:

```
Vector2D VV(2,4);
VV.setX(1).setY(5);
    //    ^ ---------  error object has no class type, you cannot use .
```

The "correct" would be `VV.setX(1)->setY(5);`. However, there is no reason to use a pointer. I know it can be difficult to understand for beginners, because in teaching pointers are overused. Most of the time you do not care about pointers or the memory adress of objects.

You return `*this`, because thats all what is needed to enable chaining. The caller has a `VV` object so what you return is a reference to that, not something else.